# How to connect my Ubuntu Server to internet

Tags: 14.04, server, ssh, internet

I know this might be a duplicate question, but I have scoured the forums and none of the answers have worked for me yet. I want to set up an ubuntu server on my old Dell laptop as it is useless as a laptop now but still works.

Here are the steps I took:

1. Created a bootable USB with Ubuntu server on it using unetbootin
2. Set up Ubuntu Server with SSH, LAMP to connect via my WIFI connection
3. Got the server working and logged in
4. trying to run `sudo apt-get update` results in the following errors (sorry for crappy photo) [Terminal window showing error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bdk05.jpg)
5. Yes, I am located in Thailand.
6. I am using a Zyxel Router
7. ifconfig reveals my inet addr to me 127.0.0.1, localhost

I don't know if this is a configuration issue or related to my router not allowing me to create a server.

Hopefully my question isn't too vague. If anyone could direct me on where I might be going wrong that would be cool!

Thanks

Comment: What kind of server(s) are you trying to set up?  Web? ssh? ftp? vpn?

Comment: It's an SSH server as far as I'm aware. I'm using a LAMP stack and operating through SSH. Basically I want to be able to host websites on there

Comment: To access an ssh server from outside your lan, you need to forward the appropriate port in your router to your server pc. Otherwise connection requests stop in the router.  then ypu need to determine what your external ip address is.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have an ip address. see https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html

I couldnt find a good primer on ipv4 or routing to link you to. this one should get you started, http://computer.howstuffworks.com/internet/basics/question549.htm also look up how routers, and nat (network address translation) works.

you'll want to forward to traffic to your new server if you intend to reach it from outside your home network. the docs at netfilter.org can tell you how to do this.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I'm using wifi but the examples assume using ethernet. However, whatever command I run I get "Device not found" message. Here is an example of trying to create temp ip address:
sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 or sudo ifconfig wlan0 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have to make sure that wireless interface is actually detected

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

If not, you need to install suitable drivers for the wireless card.

If it is detected, you need to make sure that wireless interface is listed in */etc/network/interfaces*, look for lines or create them

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
```

Then you'll need to connect to the wireless access point, actual steps depend on your wifi security, so i'll provide this link with some really nice instructions:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=571188

Comment: Thanks, it turns out my wifi card is called wlp18s0b1. Crazy!

Answer (score 0):

This one work for my ubuntu server 16.04 with USB wifi adapter. 
https://www.linuxbabe.com/command-line/ubuntu-server-16-04-wifi-wpa-supplicant

Comment: Hello and welcome to AskUbuntu;  It is good practice here to summarize the content of the link you refer to;  This way, your answer remains valid even if the link vanishes.